# What is causing my C program to display incorrect aggregate and percentage marks?

Tags: c, syntax

My program is not accepting inputs. I wrote this code and when I run it on my visual code it shows an error and when I run it on an online IED it displays bogus output.

```
/* finding aggregate and percentage marks of a student */
/* author-akshat khatri date 29-05-2023 */

#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    float m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, agr, per;

    printf("enter value of m1");
    scanf("%f", &m1);
    printf("enter value of m2");
    scanf("%f", &m2);
    printf("enter value of m3");
    scanf("%f", &m3);
    printf("enter value of m4");
    scanf("%f", &m4);
    printf("enter value of m5");
    scanf("%f", &m5);
    agr = m1 + m2 + m3 + m4 + m5;
    per = agr / 5;
    printf("aggregate marks of a student=%f", agr);
    printf("percentage marks of a student=%f", per);
    return 0;
}
```

The output now is:

```
enter value of m1enter value of m2enter value of m3enter value of m4enter value of m5aggregate marks of a student=320.000000percentage marks of a student=64.000000
```

The values of aggregate and % are fine but it's still not giving values of the marks entered in m1, m2, m3, m4, and m5.

Comment: Pay attention to compiler diagnostics. And if you aren't getting them, adjust your settings so you do. ["warning: format '%d' expects argument of type 'int *', but argument 2 has type 'float *' "](https://godbolt.org/z/xPxvE57Wd) See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for table of format specifiers. Don't know about your VS code issue.

Comment: Go to [some documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) scroll about 1/3 of the way down an you will find a table of format specifiers and accompanying length modifiers. Spend some time figuring out the table and you will learn that for float variable input, you don't use a length modifier, but a %f specifier would be appropriate.

Comment: actually i got your point i tweaked my code a little and i m still looking at the format specifier table ..,thank you

Comment: Instead of a heap of unrelated variables, consider using an array. It's also important to **check the return value** of functions that can and will fail, like `scanf`. If you proceed after an error you enter dangerous territory.

Comment: can you explain the return value point in more detail

Comment: Adjusted program now inputs and calculates correctly when given input. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/zYh4x4qd8) Don't know about VS code. I do note that you are specifying that you want output to go to a .3 file (problem1.3) and you are getting a message about a .3 file

Comment: `scanf` can fail, and if it does, you need to be paying attention. If it fails the values you think are initialized might not be, and if you use those, then you're deep into *undefined behaviour*. See [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more detail.

Comment: When parsing input like this it might make more sense to read in an entire line, then step through that with a pointer to find the delimiters. This makes it easier to have a lenient parser that can handle `5.3,3.1` as well as `5.3, 3.1` and so on.

Comment: Please show a terminal session (as text) of how you provided input to this program.